# US border stamp validity

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I am visiting a friend in the US and I was given a stamp on the passport on arrival: 7th March till 4 June. However, I will leave on the 26th of April for three weeks in Indonesia and then re-enter the US border.

Will I be given a new stamp on re-entering from Indonesia or my stamp will still be valid and expiring the 4th of June?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you were only going to Canada, Mexico, or Caribbean islands, then you probably won't get a new VWP admission period when you come back, but since you are going beyond that, you will be given a new 90-day VWP admission period when you come back (assuming that they let you in at all, of course). Make sure your ESTA is still valid on the day you come back.